# How can I permanently declare a Bash function so I don't have to do it in every session?

Tags: command-line, bash, 18.04

I tried to create my own command to run Clion from terminal and I found a way to declare a function without creating a script. I run this command in terminal:

```
function CLion { /opt/clion/bin/clion.sh "$1"; }
```

So any time I want to run the app I call the function name,
but when I restart my PC I have to declare it again and again, any solution?

Answer (score 3):

Save the definition into the `.bashrc` file located in your `$HOME` directory.